# Google map ios - how to keep the marker info window always displayed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to keep the info window from disappearing. To show it I've used

```
[mapView_ setSelectedMarker:marker];
```

But when the user taps the map somewhere the info window disappears. I've tried re-setting it at `didTapAtCoordinate` but this is called before deselecting any markers. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key Value Observing is the design pattern for this case. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387044/can-i-intercept-marker-deselect-when-i-tap-another-marker-in-google-maps-sdk-for) works for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.shouldShowInfoView = NO;
  [self.mapView addObserver:self
            forKeyPath:@"selectedMarker"
               options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                        NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
               context:NULL];
}

- (void)needToShowInfoView {
  self.shouldShowInfoView = YES;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

  if ([keyPath isEqual:@"selectedMarker"]) {
    if (self.shouldShowInfoView) {
      if ([[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        self.mapView.selectedMarker = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to test out Hanton's solution in **Swift 4**, simplified to just always show the info window as soon as the page is loaded:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedMarker", options: [.new, .old], context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "selectedMarker" {
        if change?[.newKey] as? NSObject is NSNull {
            mapView.selectedMarker = change?[.oldKey] as? GMSMarker
        }
    }
}
```

This does work, though there is a brief flash of the info window disappearing and reappearing when the user taps.