# Can I intercept marker deselect when I tap another marker in Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I know that I can use `didTapAtCoordinate` that will deselect the marker when I tap else where on the map. 
But If there are multiple marker and I tap another one (Ex. MarkerA -> MarkerB), Is there any call back when the previous marker DidDeselect?.
I look around in `GMSMapView` the but can't find any thing I can use.

I want to change the marker color or image when it being selected and change it back when another marker select or the marker deselect.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [doco](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#a13d41c8eafc158f95bd7e4d0b052c8f5) for `selectedMarker` says:

> The marker that is selected. Setting this property selects a
>   particular marker, showing an info window on it. If this property is
>   non-nil, setting it to nil deselects the marker, hiding the info
>   window. **This property is observable using KVO.**

So, you could use [Key Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to be notified of changes to `selectedMarker`. If you use `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld` when setting up KVO (described in more detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html)), you will be notified of the old value, ie the marker which was deselected.

Comment: It took me some time to figure how KVO work. And it work perfectly Thank you.