# didUntap Event for GMSMarkers in GoogleMaps SDK iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm creating an app where I'm plotting a few points on a map. When I select a marker, I want its opacity to change, but when i unselect it, I want its opacity to change back to normal. I am only able to do the first part. What can I do for the second part? Is there an event called didUntapMarker event or something else that I can do for this?

Comment: What you have done? Add some code.

Comment: You could use Key Value Observing on `selectedMarker` to be notified when a marker is deselected. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387044/can-i-intercept-marker-deselect-when-i-tap-another-marker-in-google-maps-sdk-for